# How to carry a logged in user session to an external json.php

Tags: php, mysql, json, variables, session

Does anyone know how to carry a session to a page that the form doesn't call?

Example:

I have a login form which goes to a page that displays the Calendar.
I can carry the session of the login to the Calendar page but the calendar is feeding off another external json.php page.

I'd like to be able to carry the same username to that external json.php page if possible without appending it to json.php?username (as that would present some more security risks)

I appreciate anyone's ideas on how to resolve this.

Code Example of Json:
Currently "$_SESSION['user']" doesn't pull the username.

```
session_start();
include_once 'db.php';

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user']."' ORDER BY start ASC");

$arr = array();

while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
$arr[] = $obj;
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: `SESSION` values can be retrieved from any page provided its on the same domain and session is initialized on top of both the pages i.e. 1. Where session variable is created and 2. Where session value is read. In your case you have started the session with `session_start();` so it should work. You can try printing session values with `echo '<pre>`; print_r($_SESSION);` after session is started.

Comment: You shouldn't need to continue to pass login information from page to page, instead you should be storing a session cookie to the user's browser in your login script, that your code can check against on every page load.

Comment: Thanks @Samir for your input on the sessions, they were working but I am glad to know they carry over multiple pages either way.

Comment: Thank you as well @Frodo your suggestion to use Cookies was a much better decision which I was able to easily implement.